# C++: how to make std::unique_ptr<int> point to a new integer?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have the following code:

```
int my_function(int x) {
    return x+1;
}

void find_my_next_idx(std::unique_ptr<int> my_idx_ptr) {
    // do something here
    // update my_idx_ptr
}

std::unique_ptr<int> my_idx_ptr = std::make_unique<int>(my_function(5));
if (!my_flag) {
    int a = 4;
    my_idx_ptr.reset(std::move(&a));
}

find_my_next_idx(my_idx_ptr); // --> error line
```

Then I got the following error:

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::unique_ptr<int>'
```

What did I do wrong? and how do I make `my_idx_ptr` point to different integer value? Thanks!

Comment: The code you post would not produce that error. Please post a the exact code that causes the error message

Comment: Also `my_idx_ptr.reset(std::move(&a));` is a logic error, it could be `my_idx_ptr = std::make_unique<int>(a);`. But that is nothing to do with your error message. The message should be associated with a line number that tells you where the error actually was.

Comment: The code above will compile but will result in UB when `my_idx_ptr` is destroyed. It won't do what you are probably hoping it will do.

Comment: Sorry, updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `unique_ptr` to contain the value of 4, you can simply do:

```
my_idx_ptr = std::make_unique(4);
```

You do not have to worry about what happens to the previous object when you do this because it destroys previous object and takes ownership of the new object.

And since `unique_ptr` cannot be copied (this is the cause of the error when you call `find_my_next_idx`), you can either:

1. pass the `unique_ptr` by reference
2. use `std::move` on it in the function call.

The first option would require you to change your function prototype to:

```
void find_my_next_idx(std::unique_ptr<int>& my_idx_ptr);
```

And the second option would require you to call like this:

```
find_my_next_idx(std::move(my_idx_ptr));
```

Answer (score 0):

std::unique_ptr stores a pointer internally, so it stores its data with new on the heap. You are trying to std::move a pointer from a local variable on the stack, this is wrong, since the local variable is destroyed at the vlosing }.

Try simply using my_idx_ptr = std::make_unique(5);

Usually, you very rarely use std:: move, since the compiler will choose the correct functions based on whether the variable is a lvalue or rvalue.

Answer (score 0):

`unique_ptr` cannot be copied, but you can move it:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> my_idx_ptr = std::make_unique<int>(my_function(5));
if (!my_flag) {
    int a = 4;
    my_idx_ptr.reset(std::move(&a));
}

find_my_next_idx( std::move(my_idx_ptr) );
```

You should not pass pointer to local variable to `unique_ptr`, because `unique_ptr` deletes owned objects by `delete` operator, managed objects should be allocated onto heap not stack - like `a` variable.

```
my_idx_ptr.reset(new int(a)); // create new int onto heap
```